# Is "Darboux" homotopy trivial?

Tags: homotopy-theory, connectedness

By Darboux function between two topological spaces I will understand any function that maps connected subsets to connected subsets.

If $f,g$ are two Darboux functions then Darboux homotopy between them is the usual homotopy except it is assumed to be Darboux instead of continuous.

I remember hearing some time ago that for any two topological spaces, every two Darboux functions on them are Darboux homotopic. Is that true?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding something, but what about the two maps $S^0\rightarrow S^0$, one of which is constant and the other of which is the identity.

Comment: @Tyrone how to prove that these are not Darboux homotopic?

Comment: Well, $\{0\}\times I$ has to map into a connected set, which is one of the points, right? So you can’t switch values.

Comment: That was my guess. Use $S^0\times I=I\sqcup I$. Then if $F$ is a Darboux homotopy between the two maps I suggest, on one summand of its domain it is a path in the ordinary sense between the two disjoint points of $S^0$.

Comment: Right, this looks correct. @Tyrone I will accept this is as an answer. I wonder though if we additionally assume that both spaces are path connected, does it make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will explain the counter example from the comments.

Write $S^0=\partial I=\{0,1\}$. Let $f:S^0\rightarrow S^0$ be the identity and $g:S^0\rightarrow S^0$ the constant map at $1$. Then these two maps are not Darboux homotopic. For $S^0\times I\cong I\sqcup I$, so a Darboux homotopy between them would a Darboux map
$$F:I\sqcup I\rightarrow S^0$$
which would necessary spread one summand of its domain over both the disjoint points in its target.

As an answer to the questions raised in comments, I found the paper *On c-Homotopies* by J. Pawlak, published in Real Analysis Exchange, *21*, 1995-96, 424–429.

Pawlak calls Darboux maps and homotopies *connected* maps and homotopies, or c-maps and c-homotopies for short. He write $f\cong h$ when $f,g$ are c-homotpic c-maps. In the paper just cited he proves as Theorem 2 the following statement

> Let $f,h:X→Y$ be connected  functions. Then $f\cong h$ if and only if for each component $Z$ of $X$ there exists a connected set $C_Z\subseteq Y$ such that the  cardinality of $CZ$ is less than or equal to that of the continuum and $f(Z)\cap C_Z\neq\emptyset\neq h(Z)\cap C_Z$.